# How can I unserialize my query results from MYSQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, serialization

How my code looks now

```js
 $client = $_GET['client_number_search'];
 

$sql=("SELECT * FROM tobytemp.fcl_reports WHERE client_number = '" . $client . "'");

$result = $dbLink->query($sql);




$arr = array();
 
while ($r = $result->fetch_object()) {
   $temp=[
      "client_number" => $r->client_number,
      "client_name" => $r->client_name,
      "service" => unserialize($r->service),
      "volume" => $r->volume,
      "deliver_point" => $r->deliver_point,
      "port_orgin" => $r->port_orgin,
      "size" => $r->size
   ];

    array_push($arr,$temp);

}
 
 echo json_encode($arr);





/* ERROR

Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error



*/
```

Current Data populated in my table like this -

```
service - a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Inport";i:1;s:6:"Export";}
```

I would like it to be shown something like -

```
Service-
Import
Export
```

(I CANT USE PHP ON MY `clientreports.html` page as I want to later use this as an APP on Phone gap).

**AJAX CALL (clientreports.html)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#show_clientx").click(function(e) {

        $("table#client_profile").empty();

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://cmlsys/toby/client_profile.php?client_number_search=" + $("#client_number").val(),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(html) {

                //  $("table#client_profile").append('<tr><th>Client Number</th><th>Client Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>');

                jQuery.each(html, function(key, value) {

                    $("table#client_profile").append('<tr><td>' + value.client_number + '</td><td> client_name - ' + value.client_name + '</td></tr><tr></br><td>service - ' + value.service + '</td></br><td>size - ' + value.size + '</td></br><td>volume - ' + value.volume + '</td></br><td>deliver_point -' + value.deliver_point + '</td></br><td>port_orgin - ' + value.port_orgin + '</td></tr>');

                });

            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log("Error: " + e);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**TO - client_profile.php**

```
$client = $_GET['client_number_search'];

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM tobytemp.fcl_reports WHERE client_number = '".$client.
    "'");

$result = $dbLink - > query($sql);            

$arr = array();

while ($r = $result - > fetch_object()) {

    array_push($arr, array("client_number" => $r - > client_number, "client_name" => $r - > client_name, "service" => $r - > service, "size" => $r - > size, "volume" => $r - > volume, "deliver_point" => $r - > deliver_point, "port_orgin" => $r - > port_orgin));

}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Please Help

Answer (score 4):

use unserialize in php

for example

```
$demo=unserialize('a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Inport";i:1;s:6:"Export";}');

echo json_encode($demo);
```

on your code you can change while loop

```
while ($r = $result->fetch_object()) {
   $temp=[
      "client_number" => $r->client_number,
      "client_name" => $r->client_name,
      "service" => unserialize($r->service),
      "volume" => $r->volume,
      "deliver_point" => $r->deliver_point,
      "port_orgin" => $r->port_orgin,
      "size" => $r->size
   ];

    array_push($arr,$temp);

}
```

Comment: Nothing is displayed. I tried this --- 

 $US=unserialize($arr);
 
 echo json_encode($US);

Comment: no dont do that, I edit your code unserilize only `$r - > service`

Comment: (Thankyou for the help) I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I use your while loop.

Comment: its a white space and I remove it. you can try it now

Comment: Please don't give up on me :) @DeveloperH

Comment: there is a log file for errors can you copy last errors there?

Comment: I will not give up until you fix your issue

Comment: Iv got it working using abit of mine and yours haha :D thank you

Comment: I have a REP of 11 when I get to 15 im allowed to rate answers. The second I hit 15 I will :) @DeveloperH

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = array();

while ($r = $result->fetch_object()){
    array_push($arr, array (
    "client_number" => $r ->client_number, 
    "client_name" => $r->client_name, 
    "service" => unserialize($r ->service),
    "size" => unserialize($r ->size),
    "volume" => unserialize($r ->volume),
    "deliver_point" => unserialize($r ->deliver_point),
    "port_orgin" => unserialize($r ->port_orgin))
    );

}



echo json_encode($arr);
```